# Java HttpClient throws SSLHandshakeException when executing GET to https url

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I'm running a small main (in Java 8, version 1.8.0.112) to try and execute an HTTP request to an "**https**" url, lets call it "original_url". I'm using a standard CloseableHttpClient, creating it this way:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
            .build();
```

But when I hit:

```
httpClient.execute(request);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

(Full stacktrace bellow)

The weird thing is that when I reach different "https" urls from the same java code it works fine. Also, when I reach the "original_url" from Chrome or Postman (REST client) I succeed reaching to it. I also tried executing the http call to the "original_url" from a php code and it works fine.

I looked for many answers in StackOverflow, all trying to set the HttpClient to ignore unknown certificates, but it didn't work. Also it seems the certificate of the site isn't expired since I can reach to the "original_url" site from Chrome/Postman/php code.

Could it be there is a problem with the JVM keystore? Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the full exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
at com.taboola.jobs.crawler.geoedge.RestAdapterBuilder.main(RestAdapterBuilder.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: A handshake error can be lots of different things but is **almost never associated with server certificate validation** which means that **disabling validation will not help**. It might be no shared ciphers, no common protocol version, missing client certificates etc but this is unknown from the provided information. If this is a publicly accessible site I recommend to add the URL to your question.

Comment: add this `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to print more information